# How to test Controller that returns Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>>?

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I'm pretty new to webflux and I am struggling to understand how to test this Controller function.

```
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> functionName(final Request request) {
    RequestDto Dto = RequestMapper.
            INSTANCE.toDto(request);
    service.functionName(Dto);
    return Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`WebTestClient`](https://spring.getdocs.org/en-US/spring-framework-docs/docs/testing/integration-testing/webtestclient.html) that provides fluent API for verifying responses. Here is a short example

```
@WebFluxTest
class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient client;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp(ApplicationContext context) {
        client = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(context).build();
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        client.get()
                .uri("/test")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBody().isEmpty();
    }
}
```

In addition, pay attention to endpoint implementation. In reactive you need to build the flow and Webflux will subscribe to it for every request. In case, `service.functionName` is blocking (non-reactive), consider running it on a separate `Scheduler` using `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())`. For details, check [How Do I Wrap a Synchronous, Blocking Call?](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking).

If the `Callable` resolves to `null`, the resulting `Mono` completes empty and we could return `404` applying `switchIfEmpty` operator.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/test")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> functionName(Request request) {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
                RequestDto Dto = RequestMapper.INSTANCE.toDto(request);
                return service.functionName(Dto);
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .map(res -> new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK))
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)));
}
```

Comment: My service is a consumer, how does the code change if that's the case also, i have to send not_found incase there's an error in service. @Alex

Comment: What do you mean by consumer here? It's very hard to suggest something based on provided example. As for `404` not_found - you could return `null` from callable and add `.switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)))` to the flow.

Comment: Sorry, I meant my service is a void return type, thank you for your kind help! @Alex